# (Newbie) Valgrind memory leak regarding hash table creation

Tags: hash, hashtable, valgrind, cs50

Valgrind is returning me this, where the tolower use is being done in the djb2 hash function for each word passed through it. However I believe the issue is being caused by the for loop specified below if I am not mistaken

```
==649== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==649==    at 0x49DB143: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==649==    by 0x483F864: strcasecmp (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==649==    by 0x4019DC: check (dictionary.c:38)
==649==    by 0x40160B: main (speller.c:113)
==649==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==649==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==649==    by 0x401AE7: load (dictionary.c:85)
==649==    by 0x4012CE: main (speller.c:40)
```

Where I think the problem may be my for loop which

```
// generate initial null hash table, and size

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(node)); // line 85
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    
    // Return file stream to beginning to start loading into hash table
    fseek(dict, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // Puts word from dictionary into string "word1" using fscanf
    char word1[LENGTH + 1];
    wordcounter = 0;
    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word1) != EOF)
    {
        
        // Hash function will return int index for first letter of word
        if (table[hash(word1)]->next == NULL) // if it is the first in the initial array
        {
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            strcpy(n->word, word1);
            // n->word = word1;
            table[hash(word1)]->next = n;
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else // when theres a collision
        {
            node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
            strcpy(n->word, word1);
            // n->word = word1;
            n->next = table[hash(word1)]->next;
            table[hash(word1)]->next = n;
        }
        wordcounter++;
    }
```

Im guessing this way I made to create the hash table isn't exactly the most effective and causing a memory issue but I am having trouble understanding why?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not seeing the rest of the code, i can only say that using calloc() and initializing the memory allocated to zero will initialize it, and so it will no longer be saying 'Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value' (assuming no other code issues)

Comment: Well this definitely worked thank you!